# android json post data not being displayed/recieved in php

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to send a data from an android app to be displayed in a php page. According to the logs i put in place, the data is send and has correct values but on the php page, it displays an empty array:

```
Array()
```

This is my php file:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo "Post made";
  }


$JSON_Received = $_POST["JSON"];
$JSON_test = $_POST["TEST"];


$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($JSON_test);
$obj1 = json_decode($JSON_Received);
$obj2 = json_decode($json);


echo $obj1;
echo $obj;

echo $json;
echo $JSON_test;
echo $JSON_Received;

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Java Code:

```
public class confirmFragmentTab extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener,
    OnItemLongClickListener {

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "sales_list";


ListView saleListView;
ArrayList<SalesReciepts> salesReciept;
SalesListAdapter salesListAdapter;
ProductsDbHelper db, dp;
Activity activity;
Context context;

Button push;
private String POST_PRODUCTS = "http://bi.test.com/tests/products_api/post_products.php";

InputStream is = null;

private GetEmpTask task;
protected FragmentActivity mActivity;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = getActivity();
    context = getActivity();

    db = new ProductsDbHelper(activity);
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_layout, container, false);
    findViewsById(rootView);


    task = new GetEmpTask(activity);
    task.execute((Void) null);

    saleListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    saleListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    GlobalApp.data().context = getActivity();

    push.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //postList();
            new pushInvoice().execute();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void findViewsById(View view) {
    saleListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_sale);
    push = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendRecords);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
    SalesReciepts sale = (SalesReciepts) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

    if (sale != null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putParcelable("selectedSale", sale);
        CustomEditDialog customDialogFragment = new CustomEditDialog();
        customDialogFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        customDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),
                CustomEditDialog.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long arg3) {
    SalesReciepts sale = (SalesReciepts) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    // Use AsyncTask to delete from database
    db.delete(sale);
    salesListAdapter.remove(sale);
    return true;
}

public class GetEmpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<SalesReciepts>> {

    private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    public GetEmpTask(Activity context) {
        this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<SalesReciepts> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<SalesReciepts> saleList = db.getCurrentSalesRecords();
        return saleList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SalesReciepts> sList) {
        if (activityWeakRef.get() != null
                && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            Log.d("sales", sList.toString());
            salesReciept = sList;
            if (sList != null) {
                if (sList.size() != 0) {
                    salesListAdapter = new SalesListAdapter(activity,
                            sList);
                    saleListView.setAdapter(salesListAdapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Sales Records",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}


private class pushInvoice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        //ArrayList<RecieptHeader> invoiceList = db.getInvoiceHeader();
        ArrayList<SalesReciepts> entryList = db.getSalesRecords();


        List<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", String.valueOf(entryList)));
        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TEST", "HELLO"));

        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        try {


            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Setup a http post method for passing the URL in case
            // the database is offline and the ip address in case of a localhost database
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_PRODUCTS);
            //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.33/connect_to_new_table.php");

            // Pass on the names of the values inside the post
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(postVars.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    responseHandler);

            is = entity.getContent();

            if (response != null)
                Log.e("Sent", postVars.get(1).getValue().toString());
            Log.e("Response", response);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}
}
```

UPDATE:
Logs with sent values. postVars is a name value list of the values to be sent

```
08-19 10:19:22.194    1708-1725/com.example.Prototype E/Sent﹕ HELLO
08-19 10:19:22.194    1708-1725/com.example.Prototype E/Response﹕ Post madeJSON=%5BSalesReciepts+%5Bid%3D0%2C+product_description%3DBell+Lager+500ml+RET+25X01+LONGNECK%2C+qty%3D23%2C+unit%3D3658%2C+total%3D84134.0%5D%5D&TEST=HELLOHELLO[SalesReciepts [id=0, product_description=Bell Lager 500ml RET 25X01 LONGNECK, qty=23, unit=3658, total=84134.0]]Array
(
[JSON] => [SalesReciepts [id=0, product_description=Bell Lager 500ml RET 25X01 LONGNECK, qty=23, unit=3658, total=84134.0]]
[TEST] => HELLO
)
```

Comment: what is `postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", String.valueOf(entryList)));` for? 
Maybe also post here the value of the post parameters that you logged

Comment: Updated code with logs. postVars is the name value list with array, string values to send to php

Comment: How do you know that it displays an empty array? You are not even reading the echos of the php script. Further it makes no sense to use boh $_POST and php://input. Not possible.

Comment: I know its empty because print_r($_POST) displays Array() and php://input was me trying different methods

Comment: 'I know its empty because print_r($_POST) displays Array()'. But where does it display that? As said, you are not even reading the output of print_r so how would you know? And if it is empty then how can you say that the values are correct? You could take some more effort to explain what happens and not happens. As explained now it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing some weeks ago and I get JSON data with this istruction:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

and then with json['nameVar'] i get the values.

You can find my project on [Github](https://github.com/filippofavaro/Here) if it can helps you.

Comment: no luck. interestingly, i can post to wamp but not a live server